# xamp installation stuck at 73%

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, php, xampp

I downloaded xamp from the website, then converted it to an installable format , I ran sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-8.2.12-0-installer.run  the installation process keeps getting stuck at 73%